# When the dereference operator (*) is overloaded, is the usage of *this affected?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, this, dereference

For example,

```
class Person{
        string name;
    public:
        T& operator*(){
            return name;
        }
        bool operator==(const Person &rhs){
            return this->name == rhs.name;
        }
        bool operator!=(const Person &rhs){
            return !(*this == rhs); // Will *this be the string name or the Person?
        }
}
```

If `*this` ends up dereferencing `this` to a `string` instead of a `Person`, is there a workaround that maintains the usage of `*` as a dereference operator outside the class?

It would be quite a hindrance if I couldn't overload `*` without giving up usage of `*this`.

Comment: The overload applies to Person objects. But `this` is a person *pointer*.

Comment: @Galik this comment should be an (accepted) answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> If `*this` ends up dereferencing `this` to a string instead of a `Person`, is there a workaround that maintains the usage of `*` as a dereference operator outside the class?

No. `*this` will be `Person&` or `Person const&` depending on the function. The overload applies to `Person` objects, not pointers to `Person` objects. `this` is a pointer to a `Person` object.

If you use:

```
 Person p;
 auto v = *p;
```

Then, the `operator*` overload is called.

To call the `operator*` overload using `this`, you'll have to use `this->operator*()` or `**this`.

Comment: Suggest you incorporate @Galik's explanation in your answer.

Answer (score 12):

You need an object of the class rather than the pointer to class object to invoke the overloaded `*` operator.

```
Person *ptr = new Person;
Person p1 = *ptr;   // does not invoke * operator but returns the object pointed by ptr
string str = *p1 // invokes the overloaded operator as it is called on an object.
```

Same is the case with `this` pointer. To invoke `* operator` with `this` pointer, you will have to dereference twice:

```
std::string str = *(*this);
```